# Differentiability in zero

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the function given by,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      x^2+kx+m & -\frac{\pi}{2}<x< 0 \\
      \tan(x)+\cos(x) & 0\leq x< \frac{\pi}{2}
   \end{cases}$$

I now want to determine $k$ and $m$ such that $f$ is differentiable in $x=0$.

Furthermore, I want to determine $k$ such that the line $k=y-36x$ is perpendicular to the following curve given by,

$$y=\frac{1}{|x-7|}$$

For the first task I concluded $m=1$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$. Is this correct, for the second task, I have not made any progress

Comment: You should post these tasks separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Continuity :**

$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x)=f(0)\\\Longrightarrow m=\tan 0 + \cos 0 \\ \Longrightarrow m=1$

**Differentiability :**

$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
2x+k &-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<0\\
\sec^2x-\sin x &0\leq x<\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{cases} \\
\Longrightarrow 2\cdot 0 +k=\sec^2 0-\sin 0 \\
\Longrightarrow k=1$

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain 2 equations- one for continuity and other for differentiability.

**CHECKING CONTINUITY**

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      x^2+kx+m & -\frac{\pi}{2}<x< 0 \\
      \tan(x)+\cos(x) & 0\leq x< \frac{\pi}{2}
   \end{cases}$$
$$\lim_{h \to0^+}h^2-kh+m=\tan h +\cos h$$
$$\implies \boxed{m=1}$$

**CHECKING DIFFERENTIABILITY**
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases} 
      2x+k & -\frac{\pi}{2}<x< 0 \\
      \sec^2(x)-\sin(x) & 0\leq x< \frac{\pi}{2}
   \end{cases}$$
$$\lim_{h \to0^+}-2h+k=\sec^2(h)-\sin(h)$$

I'll let you conclude.